# How can I make a good use of the JSF 2.0 framework?

Tags: jsf-2

Currently I have only one controller AppController (*SessionScope - ManagedBean*) that handles all of the requests and logic of my system, but somehow this doesn't seem right. I want to make this project as modular as possible so it can be very easy to maintain.

I have read a little about *Dependency Injection*, but I just can't make it work, that is, I don't know what's the issue with the "scope" of the beans. For example, I have my AppController and my Users bean, but I can't make use of the AppController from the Users bean (although I have tried with dependency injection). I think that the logic of the users (edit names, set relationships, etc.) must be handled by the Users bean, but right now those tasks are handled by the AppController, which doesn't seem right.

The issue is, Is there any good tutorial where I can learn how to make a proper use of the JSF 2.0 framework? My objective is to make the AppController as light as possible. I have found several tutorials, but they seem to be more focused on older versions of the JSF or I just don't happen to understand them (maybe they are too technical, I don't know).

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the concrete problem, you shouldn't have a single managed bean which acts as a front controller to handle all requests. JSF's own `FacesServlet` is supposed to do that. The common consensus is to have a single request/view scoped managed bean per `<h:form>` you have. And one or two session scoped bean(s) to represent the logged-in user and its settings like locale, if any. You could have an application scoped bean for applicationwide data such as dropdown constants.

As to the concrete question (which is rather subjective and per definition offtopic here, but ala), there is not really a simple tutorial for this. It's a matter of understanding what you're doing and what the code is doing and ultimately using the right tool for the job. In order to learn that, you've to read a self-respected JSF2 book from top to bottom and play a lot around with simple projects. JSF can't be learnt and fully understood in 1 day. It took me years. You can find useful links/references in [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: I get your point. I think that I will read a lot more and check if I can accomplish what I'm trying to do. Although this is for a school project, I'm willing to make everything right. As a start, I'm reading the Book JavaServer Faces 2.0: The Complete Reference; it seems nice and maybe it'll get through this particular issue. Thanks!